# Inserting MS-SQL server Text type into MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, insert

I have a SQL 2008 R2 server linked with a MySQL 5.5 server.
When I try to insert a Text column from the SQL server into a Text column in the MySQL server it fails.
Query -

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT bio FROM d.test')
SELECT bio FROM test.dbo.ARTIST
where art_no = 3
```

the bio column in the SQL Server is type text - SQL_Latin_General_CP1_CI_AS and the bio column in the MySQL server is type text - charater set Latin1 collate - latin1_general_ci

The errors I get are:

> > Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> >     The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
> >
> > Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
> >     The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]". Unknown provider error.

Comment: http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

Comment: If you are using SQL 2008R2 you should be aware that `TEXT, NTEXT, and IMAGE` has been deprecated in favor of `VARCHAR(MAX), NVARCHAR(MAX), and VARBINARY(MAX)`

Answer (score 0):

The `TEXT` data type in MS SQL is an odd / "second class" creature. Any chance you could convert the column to nvarchar(max)? If so, it's possible that might resolve your linked server issue. The T-SQL to change the column type looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTableName] ALTER COLUMN [YourColumnName] nvarchar(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a workaround:

```
 INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT bio FROM d.test')
       SELECT CAST(bio as varchar(max))
       FROM test.dbo.ARTIST
       where art_no = 3
```